# UE4 PUT Request to Firebase using Va Rest Plugin

Tags: json, rest, firebase, put, unreal-blueprint

I am currently trying to implement a cloud save feature for an android mobile game that has been developed using UE4.17.2 Blueprints. After a load of research, I have decided to use Firebase for this and to communicate with the real time database using [VaRest Plugin](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/VaRest_Plugin).

I got the GET request working for a firebase URL so receiving data is no problem.
However I **cannot** find a way to get my PUT Request working.
The aim of the **PUT request** is to update the 'Coins' value of a specific user.

[image: PUT REQUEST BLUEPRINT CODE HERE]

The data values are not being updated and I am receiving this error:

[image: ERROR PRINT]

Any Idea on what I did wrong and what is the correct way to get a PUT request working in UE4 blueprints?

Answer (score 2):

So I tried out a lot of things with Va Rest and finally found the solution!

[Solution Snapshot!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INXJM.png)

1. I first changed the Verb Attribute of the Construct JSON Request to PUT, and set the Content Type of the same Node to JSON.

   2. Then I merely used the node "Set Integer Field", where the Field Name was the name of the attribute I wanted to save the value to, that value being Number (Previous Coins + No.of Orbs).
   3. Then I construct the CURL by appending 3 literal strings before it passing it onto the Process URL Node.
   4. If you want to, you can print out the response content value (New Value of Coins) through a custom event.